# Python string manipulation { _teststr[2:12:-1]) }

Tags: python, string

I just started learning Python, and I was just getting into strings.
So I have 3 commands here

```py
_teststr = "IneedToFocusOnMyFuture"
print('1.',_teststr[::-1])
print('2.',_teststr[2:12:2])
print('3.',_teststr[2:12:-1])
```

Output:

```
1. erutuFyMnOsucoFoTdeenI
2. edoou
3.
```

Why the 3rd output is blank instead of having `'uoode'`? What is going under  the hood? Could anyone please explain?

Comment: With a negative step, you go in the reverse direction. `_teststr[11:1:-1]` would work.

Comment: when you call indexation in python arrays the general sintax is  [start:end:step] when you cannot get to `end from `start`using `strep` then it returns a void array (you cannot gro from 2 to 12 by step -1 cause if you start counting you get 2, 1, 0, -1... ). So you need to `start` at 12 and `end` in 2 if you'are using a negative step

Comment: @Reti43, thanks, but I just wanna know what _teststr[2:12:-1]actually  instructing to the interpreter  to perform?  looking for an explanation as I need to understand how the  underlying flow works. thank you :)

Comment: thanks @UlisesBussi, that makes sense!

Comment: Think of it like this: `if (step > 0 and end > start) or (step < 0 and start > end) slice_object() else return_empty_container()`

Comment: thanks @Reti43 , got it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to reverse the specific string.

```py
print('3.',_teststr[2:12][::-1])
```

Lets understand the syntax

```
str[start:end:step]
```

start denotes from where to splice and end denotes where to end the splice.
The step parameter denotes the number of elements to leave after a successful splicing.By default step is 1.

### Example:

```
str="naveen"
str[1:3] //av
#with including step
str[1:3:1] //av
str[1:4:2] //ae
step defines the number of elements to leave after a consideration.So it cant be negative.
```

Comment: this and Reti43 and UlisesBussi s comment answers my question. thank you!